# Altering brigthness on OpenGL texture

Tags: opengl, textures

I would like to increase the brightness on a texture used in OpenGL rendering. Such as making it bright red or white. This is a 2D rendering environment, where every sprite is mapped as a texture to an OpenGL polygon.
I know little to nothing on manipulating data, and my engine works with a texture cache, so altering the whole surface would affect everything using the texture.
I can simulate the effect by having a "mask" and overlaying it, allowing me to make the sprite having solid colors, but that takes away memory.
If there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement afford it, you can always write a very simple GLSL fragment shader which does this. It's literally a one liner.
Something like:

```
uniform sampler2d tex;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2d(tex, gl_TexCoord[0]) + gl_Color;
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving an example. You should probably move to using shaders instead of the fixed pipleline anyway, it's just so much more flexible

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [GL_ADD](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml) instead of GL_MODULATE?

Answer (score 0):

use `GL_MODULATE` to multiply the texture color by the current color.
see the texture tutorial in [this page](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html).

Comment: It doesn't work too well, and it's the default it seems, so I am using it already. When using a sprite and setting color (1,0,0) (full red) it literally removes green and blue from the sprite. I would like to add actual red instead of removing the other two components.